# Regex to match several possible permutations of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence which can be either of the following:

```
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar with limit 1
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar with offset 1
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar with filter eq(foo, bar)
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar with limit 1 and offset 1
for the thing with the some.key Foo Bar with limit 1 and offset 1 and filter eq(foo, bar)
```

I'm using the regular expression (PCRE2)

```
for the thing with the (\S+) (.*(?= with)?)(?: with )(?:limit (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:offset (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:filter (.+))?
```

It doesn't match the top sentence (without "with").

I thought `(.*(?= with)?)` would mean "anything, then maybe a 'with'" but I'm wrong.

Regex101 to show matches:

[image]

Comment: `(?: with )` requires `with` with spaces around it. `(?= with)?` is pointless since you say "require this, but make it optional".

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew but that then removes the capture of the integers and filter expression. Everything after `with` is matched in one group

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/YeN4K4/2

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "sentence", considering that your examples do not begin with capital letter and have no punctuation at the end.  Of particular interest is whether the given string can be a substring of a longer string, and if so, whether the given string is always at the end of the encompassing string.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that your optional group boundaries are off, and you must have made the `(?: with )` pattern optional. Besides, the `.*` pattern is too greedy, you need to both replace this with a lazy version, and add an end of string anchor at the end, `$`.

You can use

```
for the thing with the (\S+) (.*?)(?: with (?:limit (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:offset (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:filter (.+))?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeN4K4/3).

*Details*:

- `for the thing with the`  - a literal text
- `(\S+)`` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces
- - a space
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than line breaks as few as possible
- `(?: with (?:limit (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:offset (\d+))?(?: and )?(?:filter (.+))?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `with`  - a literal text
  - `(?:limit (\d+))?` - an optional sequence of `limit` + space + Group 3 capturing one or more digits
  - `(?: and )?` - an optional sequence of space + `and` + space
  - `(?:offset (\d+))?` - an optional sequence of `offset` + space and Group 4 capturing one or more digits
  - `(?: and )?` - an optional sequence of space + `and` + space
  - `(?:filter (.+))?` - an optional sequence of `filter` + space + Group 5 capturing all the rest of the line till the first line break char
- `$` - end of string.
  `

Comment: Equivalent, except defined in free-spacing mode with named capture groups is [here](https://regex101.com/r/Lmu0WV/1). (Note that whitespace that is part of the regex must be protected when free-spacing mode is used. There are several ways to do that. I've simply escaped space characters.)